# Bundling app with SystemJS using 3rd party library?

Tags: systemjs

How can I get the systemjs builder to ignore third party libraries?  We are evaluating wijmo controls for use in an app and they provide `wijmo.angular2.min.js`, `wijmo.input.min.js` and `wijmo.min.js`.  We load these after SystemJS in our web page and that works fine because those files register the wijmo modules.  However, when we try to bundle it throws an error because it cannot find the files.  Sample error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error on fetch for vendor/wijmo/wijmo.angular2.input.js
at file:///C:/git/prj/dist/vendor/wijmo/wijmo.angular2.input.js
```

I can add this path to my config but then I get a different error:

```
'wijmo/*': 'vendor/wijmo/wijmo.angular2.min.js'
```

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Error compiling register module "wijmo/wijmo.angular2.input"
at vendor\wijmo\wijmo.angular2.min.js
    Source vendor\wijmo\wijmo.angular2.min.js is already a bundle file, so can't
be built as a module.
```

***Edit***

Adding this path lets bundling work (at least it builds the bundles), but keeping the line in my config causes the app to error out, apparently being unable to find the class I'm importing (throws unexpected directive 'undefined')...

```
'wijmo/wijmo.angular2.input': 'vendor/wijmo/wijmo.input.min.js'
```

Comment: Hi Jason, could you please provide your final working settings? (I'm going crazy)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding a 'meta' section to my SystemJS config that told it not to build that path:

```
var meta = {
    'wijmo/*': {
        format: 'global',
        build: false,
    }
};
```

Comment: after this I am stuck with "Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module", did u face such errors? if yes can you please share how u overcame it?

Comment: what if I want to avoid the use of systemjs after the build? (currently I'm getting: `wijmo.angular2.min.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`

Comment: @daveoncode Sorry, I'm still no SystemJS expert and have moved to using webpack so I probably can't help much more.   But the meta setting was the only place I needed to reference wijmo in the config.  I had an NPM module named wijmo  with the files they give you in their example (can't remember which module format) and imported from `wijmo/wijmo.angular2.input` which is a `.d.ts` file in node_modules/wijmo. Using that config in bundling I think I still had to reference the wijmo js files in html before loading my bundle and after loading systemjs.